# Simple approach for running a docker image with python on ubuntu

Tags: python, bash, docker, ubuntu

The problem is that I have a python app and want to create a docker image from it. What is a simple approach to do so?

I am using a ubuntu desktop 22.04, running a python django rest_framework app using (venv) virtual environament.

I have docker 24.0.7 already intsalled and need to create a Dockerfile and know the steps to create and run a docker image.

Answer (score 1):

### **The most simple approach to run a docker container using python on ubuntu**

in the root of the project run the command to create the *requirements.txt* file containing your virtual environament packages:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

create a new '*Dockerfile*' in the project root:

```
FROM python:3.10.12
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --quiet
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

execute bash command to **build** the docker image:

```
docker build -t my-app-img:0.1.0 .
```

execute bash command to **run** the image:

```
docker run --rm -d -p 8000:8000/tcp my-app-img:0.1.0
```

access it using the browser:

```
http://localhost:8000/
```

ubuntu 22.04,python 3.10.12, docker 24.0.7, venv, django, rest_framework, restframework, image, container